# MFA for Customer Community Login Users

Tags: customer-community, mfa

I have a Community with about 500 customer community login users.  Based on information I received from Salesforce, it sounds like I need to enable MFA for these users.  I am hesitant to do that because I believe that will require them to have an authenticator on their mobile devices to login to the Community.  Is that correct or is there another option?  I feel like we are going to see a big decrease in logins if the infrequent Customer Community login users need to have an app setup on their mobile devices.

Comment: I feel that the information about this is pretty sparse too. Would be interested in the answer. Got a feeling that this will be deferred.

Comment: This is covered in MFA FAQ: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000352937&type=1&mode=1

Comment: @identigral  Based on the information Identigral linked to, MFA is not required for Community users.

"Customers' customers and partners who log in to Experience Cloud sites, e-commerce sites, help portals, and so forth aren't required to use MFA. 

Note that some local jurisdictions or industries have stricter regulatory requirements regarding MFA that can result in these types of users requiring MFA."